# why my array don`t stored the data i append?

Tags: python, list

so im trying to make a login/signup history and stored them in 1 array fill with dictionaries,so when i called array.append and print the array in the same if statement with the array.append it is actually stored in the array but when i acces the array in another if statement the data i append before its gone
this is the code

```
haveanaccount = input("did you alredy have an account?(y/n)")
database = [{"name":"aizar", "email":"aizar@gmail.com", "password":"Martistop1"}]
if haveanaccount == "n":
    print("please signup")
    name = input("name:")
    email = input("email:")
    password = input("Password:")
    database.append(signup(name, email, password, database)) 
    print(database)
    haveanaccount = "y"
if haveanaccount == "y":
    print("please login")
    email = input("email:")
    password = input("password:")
    login(email, password, database)
```

the signup function make the dictionaries, and the login function acess the data base and check if the input stored in the database or not.
im trying to read python memory management but i don`t understand it, any help i apreciate it

Comment: This has **nothing to do with** being "out of" memory, and there is **no meaningful** "memory management" in Python. If something isn't appearing in your list, it's because there's either something wrong with the code that produces the value, or the code that puts it in the list. To understand the problem properly **requires** a [mre]; we do not find the bug for you here. Please make sure that someone else can **copy and paste** the code in the question **without adding or changing anything** to see the **exact problem, directly**.

Comment: Also, we call that a *list* in Python, not an "array".

Comment: "when i acces the array in another if statement the data i append before its gone" - it's not at all clear what this means, because *you do not show any code that does any such access*.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this:

```py
def login(email, password, database):
    for user in database:
        if user["email"] == email and user["password"] == password:
            return "Login successful"
    return "Login failed"

def signup(name, email, password):
    database.append({"name":name, "email":email, "password":password})
    

haveanaccount = input("did you alredy have an account?(y/n)")
database = [{"name":"aizar", "email":"aizar@gmail.com", "password":"Martistop1"}]
if haveanaccount == "n":
    print("please signup")
    name = input("name:")
    email = input("email:")
    password = input("Password:")
    signup(name, email, password) 
    print(database)
    haveanaccount = "y"
if haveanaccount == "y":
    print("please login")
    email = input("email:")
    password = input("password:")
    print(login(email, password, database))
```

hope this helps :)